# How to include “zero” / “0” results in COUNT when WHERE is used?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to have a query that will return 0 COUNT as well as a total number of sales between month and month for my recruits.

```
SELECT recruits.pin, recruits.first_name, recruits.surname, sales.sale_date,
COUNT(sales.pin) AS 'TotalSales' FROM sales
 LEFT JOIN recruits ON sales.pin = recruits.pin
WHERE sales.sale_date BETWEEN '$sYear1-$sMonth1-01' AND '$sYear2-$sMonth2-31'
AND recruits.country = '$sCountry'
GROUP BY recruits.pin
ORDER BY COUNT(sales.pin) DESC;
```

this only outputs the total number of sales for the months selected. and does not show any 0 values, and will not show all recruits.
If I remove the WHERE statement it outputs all recruits, except it does not filter by month so I am unable to filter out number of sales by month.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no sales (sales.pin)in between the dates thats why you dont see them listed.

Comment: Make the FROM get from Recruits and LEFT JOIN Sales.
and then..COUNT(COALESCE(sales.PIN, 0))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the condition on `recruits` to the `on` clause.  But if you want all *recruits* (filtered by country), then `recruits` should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.

I would write this as:

```
SELECT r.pin, r.first_name, r.surname, s.sale_date,
       COUNT(s.pin) AS TotalSales
FROM recruits r LEFT JOIN
     sales s
     ON s.pin = r.pin AND
        s.sale_date BETWEEN '$sYear1-$sMonth1-01' AND '$sYear2-$sMonth2-31'
WHERE r.country = '$sCountry'
GROUP BY r.pin
ORDER BY COUNT(s.pin) DESC;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to read and to write.
- Normally, you would want to include all unaggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.  Presumably, `pin` is a primary key/unique key in `recruits` so this is one case where not including the columns is fine.
- The condition on `sale_date` (the second table) should go in the `on` clause.
- The condition on `country` (the first table) should go in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the where clause I would say. You should also invert the sales and recruit. Take first all recruit and then join the sales. Try to include all recruits by testing if the sales.id (select the right column name) is null or if the sales are in the periods.

```
SELECT recruits.pin, recruits.first_name, recruits.surname, sales.sale_date,
SUM(COALESCE(sales.Total,0)) AS 'TotalSales' FROM recruits
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON sales.pin = recruits.pin
WHERE sales.pin IS NULL OR sales.sale_date BETWEEN '$sYear1-$sMonth1-01' AND '$sYear2-$sMonth2-31'
AND recruits.country = '$sCountry'
GROUP BY recruits.pin
ORDER BY COUNT(sales.pin) DESC;
```

Comment: yes, whatever field that cannot be null. I changed it to [pin]

Comment: this has made some changes. but its still not correct. I get a count of 1 for a recruit with no sales what so ever.

Comment: I corrected the answer, you should do the sum of the field corresponding of the total of the sale.